# TLF text makes my SWF main symbol not able to be found

Tags: flash, flash-builder, symbols, tlf

Here is my problem, Im trying to set some text using a TLF text inside Flash CS5. I create a TLF text inside a movieclip, to later access and modify that text at runtime, the problem is, when I load the symbol of the movieclip from Flash Builder, it says that it cant be found, If I delete the TLF text, and publish it again, it works ok... I have no compilation errors.

What cuould be the issue?, doesn't matter if I assign an instance name to the text or not, as soon as I place the TLF text there, my main swf's symbol cant be found...

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to import a class for using TLF.